# Outlook crashes on calendar view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I'm running Outlook 2007 using hosted Exchange and everytime I try to go to the "calendar" screen Outlook hangs. I have to kill the process and restart Outlook.

Details:

- Fully patched Office 2007
- No third-party Outlook plug-ins
- Windows 7

Troubleshooting:

- Tried reboot
- Tried a repair/reboot
- Tried Outlook.exe /cleanviews
- Confirmed I can load my calendar in OWA
- Renamed (to force recreation) of OST file
- Tried deleting outcmd.dat

Comment: Have you talked to the host?  This may be server-side...

Comment: Have you just tried to delete the profile and create a new one? That might fix the issue... and don't check "cache mode"

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/40858/outlook-2003-only-wants-to-start-in-safe-mode-how-can-i-fix-this/40866#40866

Comment: 40858 didn't work, thanks though; I'll contact host.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft [answers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192980) this.

2nd result for Google: `exchange calendar slow`.

Comment: That QB article is for O2000, and describes Outlook starting slowly. My Outlook does not start slowly. It runs quite fast.